# Get numbers input from users separated with commas and then add those numbers to another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want the user to type the numbers separated by commas and then add those numbers to an array?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll need to start by writing some code. Once you have a *specific* problem, tell us where you got stuck, show us what you've tried, explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.) and then we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

User input can be easily collected.

In WinForms you can get it with text box, in console app you could do it with `Console.ReadLine()` method. In other frameworks you could use other ways, but the key point is that it will be a `string` variable at some point.

Then, to put it into an array, you can use following methods:

```
// userInput is string variable holding user input
var userArray = userInput.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).Torray();
```

I used `Split` method which returns array of splitted string by specified separator (comma in this example), then I used LINQ method to convert  this into `int` collection (be aware of `Parse` method which might throw an exception in case of invalid cast). At last, I used `ToArray`, which returns us array of `int`s.